# Configure .yaml for IP Aliasing

Tags: server, 22.04, netplan

I need some help to configure .yaml file on my ubuntu server 22.04.

In particular I need to configure the .yaml for a IP Aliasing cause my server has only 1 NIC but I need 2 subnets.

Example:

- Subnet1: eth0 -> 10.0.1.0/24
- Subnet2: eth0:1 -> 192.168.1.0/24

Could you please give me a good and not deprecated template of .yaml file (DNS and gateway included)?

Searching on the Web there are different templates but I don't know which one to choose.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably what you are looking for:  https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-use-multiple-addresses-on-a-single-interface

Comment: Please make this an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Terrance that's what I was looking for. Make your comment an answer so I can vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-use-multiple-addresses-on-a-single-interface you do multiple addresses by doing a label under the `addresses:` in the `.yaml` for each address you want for a single interface.

Example from that page:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 10.100.1.37/24
        - 10.100.1.38/24:
            label: "enp3s0:0"
        - 10.100.1.39/24:
            label: "enp3s0:some-label"
```